# What was the motivation for the Gregorian Calendar?

Tags: time-keeping, calendar

The Gregorian Calendar eventually replaced the Roman calendar at some point, I know this was something to do with the days not being quite accurate so specific days (I think equinox and solstice) were not consistent after some point.  So what was the motivation behind this?  If the change came centuries later wasn't it already known?

Who determined the actual time scale used, how was this established and determined, especially leap years?  Was there any analysis over the method used?

Comment: This is too old to close, but as stated, this is a trivial question answered by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar).

Comment: Hard to say if Wikipedia did answer the question at the time, I can only look back at the page history to 2013 and I asked this when we were originally added questions to the SE

Comment: I should have cited the answer, which is found in the fourth sentence of the article, "The motivation for the reform was to bring the date for the celebration of Easter to the time of the year in which the First Council of Nicaea had agreed upon in 325."  My intent was not to scold anyone, but to prevent someone from seeing this and assuming that it was ok to ask questions that are answered by wikipedia.

Comment: Wikipedia can always catch up, its a matter of whether you close older questions when it does so  Feel free to close or delete, I don't care either way, I rarely visit this SE anymore.

Comment: Agreed - Wikipedia is a moving target.

Comment: Very good presentation, with the original text in Latin of Fr. Clavius, S.J., and French translations: [_Les textes fondateurs du calendrier grégorien_](http://www.henk-reints.nl/cal/audette/calgreg.html#table) ([Google English translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&u=http://www.henk-reints.nl/cal/audette/calgreg.html%23table)).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Essentially the extra quarter of a day that the Julian leap year added was slightly longer than the 0.242 of a day left over in the actual solar year. It affected Pope Gregory XIII because the *Christian holidays were being celebrated on the wrong days*. This was noticed by the Pope's astronomers and prompted the need for change.

> [What's the science behind this?](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/GregorianCalendar.html)
>
> The calendar currently in worldwide use for secular purposes based on
>   a cycle of 400 years comprising 146,097 days, giving a year of average
>   length 365.2425 days. The Gregorian calendar is a modification of the
>   Julian calendar in which leap years are omitted in years divisible  by
>   100 but not divisible  by 400. By this rule, the year 1900 was not a
>   leap year (1900 is divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400), but the
>   year 2000 will be a leap year (2000 is divisible  by 400). The total
>   number of days in 400 years is therefore given by

The following [National Geographic Article](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/02/120229-leap-year-day-february-29-calendar-cultures-science/) does a great job of describing the advent of the Gregorian Calendar.  Also included, below, is a snippet from the [Vatican's official website](http://www.vaticanstate.va/EN/Other_Institutions/The_Vatican_Observatory.htm) and more from Science World.

> ...
>
> **Leap Year Needed to Correct Calendar Drift**
>
> We observe the modern leap year because Earth orbits the sun every 365.242 days—not
>   an easy number for a calendar to accommodate.
>
> ...
>
> The so-called Julian calendar reorganized the 12 Roman months into a 365-day year
>   with a leap year every four years. It was a tremendous improvement but
>   with a lingering flaw: The extra quarter of a day that the leap year
>   added was slightly longer than the 0.242 of a day left over in the
>   actual solar year. This seemingly small difference made the solar year
>   about 11 minutes too long, resulting in an entire day of discrepancy
>   every 128 years. Because of this glitch, the Julian calendar had
>   drifted ten days by the late 16th century. "*Finally it became so
>   ridiculous that Pope Gregory XIII was convinced by his astronomers
>   that basically all the Christian holidays were being celebrated on the
>   wrong days*," [Duncan](http://books.google.com/books/about/Calendar.html?id=orfmmdprseUC) said. The pope introduced his Gregorian calendar
>   in 1582, which determined that only one out of every four "century
>   years" would observe a leap year. Thus while the years 2000 and 2400
>   are leap years, 2100, 2200, and 2300 are not. The Gregorian calendar
>   was gradually, and sometimes grudgingly, adopted by much of the world
>   and remains in common use.
>
> ...
>
> **Source:** [National Geographic News - Leap year (why)](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2012/02/120229-leap-year-day-february-29-calendar-cultures-science/)
>
> ```
> Brian Handwerk
> for National Geographic News
> Updated February 29, 2012
> ```

---

As noted the Gregorian calendar was not wholly accepted directly after the Pope's decree. In fact, the rest of Europe did not follow suit for [more than a century](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/GregorianCalendar.html).

**NOTE:** The Vatican Observatory can be traced back to Pope Gregory XIII. At the time it was referred to as [Tower of the Winds](http://www.vaticanstate.va/EN/Other_Institutions/The_Vatican_Observatory.htm). It was from this structure that Jesuit astronomers and mathematicians studied the scientific data which would later aid in the reform of the calendar which occurred in 1582.

---

**The Protestant rejection:**
(as noted by mgb in comment)

One of the original reasons the Gregorian calendar was designed was to restore the [spring equinox to the March 21st date](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05228a.htm) ([Alexandrian Easter](http://www.polysyllabic.com/calhistory/easter/alexandrian)) that had been traditionally accepted since the [Council of Nicaea](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/413817/Council-of-Nicaea). However, because this was mandated by the Pope many Protestant countries **rejected** the change.

> **[The Gregorian Conversion](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=calhistory/gregorian)** In an age of intense religious passion, the simple fact that the Pope instituted the reform was
>   enough to make Protestant countries reject the change. The greater
>   part of protestant Germany did not switch to the Gregorian calendar
>   until 1700, the Protestant Cantons of Switzerland and Protestant
>   Netherlands until 1701. ...

**Additional resources:**

- [Easter and the Gregorian Reform](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=calhistory/gregorian/easter)
- [Dates of the Gregorian Reform](http://www.polysyllabic.com/?q=calhistory/gregorian/conversion) (Country/Region)

Comment: The protestant parts of the rest of europe didn't follow for a century - catholic countries adopted it straight away

Comment: Very nice, I like the thoroughness.

Comment: @MichaelF I added more details on the influence the spring equinox had as one of the original reasons for the Gregorian calendar. Also I added information (as pointed out by **mgb**) regarding the Protestant rejection to Gregorian Reform. And finally I provided a link which shows the dates specific Counties/Regions actually did convert. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind at all, I wanted to give others an opportunity to answer but you get the win.  =)

Comment: @mgb: Indeed. And the Russians, incredibly, didn't adopt it until the 20th century!

Comment: This is one of the several notable historical examples where some system is invented by a certain religious/social/national group yet other peoples, in full knowledge that it is superior, refuse to accept it for often bigoted/prideful reasons. e.g. Gregorian Calendar (Catholic, rejected by protestants), Metric System (French, rejected by English and others), The Copernican Revolution (partially rejected by organised Christianity for a long time). Of course, they all gave in in the end... it just a while!

Comment: Leap second is related to the subject: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second